# Retrieving Window object from Form

Tags: c#, .net, window

I was wondering if it's possible to get the Window object for the current form in C#?

For example:

Window window = theCurrentlyOpenedForm

Comment: Window is a WPF class, Form is a Winforms class.  Cats and dogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very clear what you mean by Window object.

To reference the current form, you use the keyword `"this"`.

If you mean the `hWnd` value you use for pinvoke, then you would use the `this.Handle` property.